# [OpenCv][C++] Creating a smooth, airbrush-like brush stroke, similar to Photoshop?

Tags: c++, opencv, graphics, drawing, photoshop

I have a circular brush of with a diameter of 200px and hardness of 0 (the brush is a circular gradient). The spacing between each brush is 25% of the brush diameter. However, when I compare the stroke my program draws and the stroke Photoshop draws, where all settings are equal...
[image]
It is clear that photoshop's is much smoother! I can't reduce the spacing because that causes the edges to become harder

How can i make my stroke like photoshop's?
Here is the relevant code from my program...

```
//defining a circle
Mat alphaBrush(2*outerRadius,2*outerRadius,CV_32FC1);
float floatInnerRadius = outerRadius * hardness;
for(int i = 0; i < alphaBrush.rows; i++ ){
    for(int j=0; j<alphaBrush.cols; j++ ){
        int x = outerRadius - i;
        int y = outerRadius - j;
        float radius=hypot((float) x, (float) y );
        auto& pixel = alphaBrush.at<float>(i,j);
        if(radius>outerRadius){ pixel=0.0; continue;}      // transparent
        if(radius<floatInnerRadius){ pixel=1.0; continue;}      // solid
        pixel=1-((radius-floatInnerRadius)/(outerRadius-floatInnerRadius));  // partial
    }
}

/*
(...irrelevant stuff)
*/

//drawing the brush onto the canvas
for (int j = 0; j < inMatROI.rows; j++) {
            Vec3b *thisBgRow = inMatROI.ptr<Vec3b>(j);
            float *thisAlphaRow = brushROI.ptr<float>(j);
            for (int i = 0; i < inMatROI.cols; i++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                    thisBgRow[i][c] = saturate_cast<uchar>((brightness * thisAlphaRow[i]) + ((1.0 - thisAlphaRow[i]) * thisBgRow[i][c]));
                }
            }
        }
```

I have also tried resultValue = max(backgroundValue, brushValue), but the intersection between the two circles is pretty obvious.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal complete working code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My algorithm is pretty standard - I have a series of points, I draw a line between each of these points, and draw a brush along the connected lines every x number of steps where x is diameter times spacing(200*.25=50px). The two bits of code you see above are where I generate the brush and where I draw the brush.

Comment: imho you can't do this well with circular sampling of the stroke. Compute the stroke and afterward compute the gradient with actual distance to the stroke (e.g. distance transform or nearest neighbor search). So in detail after drawing the line between the set of points, compute the distances to the line-pixels (not a subsampling) and set gradient colors according to that distance.

Answer (score 1):

this is the approach, drawing a solid thin line and afterwards computing the distance of each pixel to that line.
As you can see there are some artifacts, probably mostly because of only approximated distance values from cv::distanceTransform. If you compute the distances precisely (and maybe in double precision) you should get very smooth results.

[image]

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat canvas = cv::Mat(768, 768, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar::all(255));

    cv::Mat canvasMask = cv::Mat::zeros(canvas.size(), CV_8UC1);

    // make sure the stroke has always a size of >= 2, otherwise will be cv::line way not work...
    std::vector<cv::Point> strokeSampling;
    strokeSampling.push_back(cv::Point(250, 100));

    strokeSampling.push_back(cv::Point(250, 200));
    strokeSampling.push_back(cv::Point(600, 300));
    strokeSampling.push_back(cv::Point(600, 400));
    strokeSampling.push_back(cv::Point(250, 500));

    strokeSampling.push_back(cv::Point(250, 650));

    for (int i = 0; i < strokeSampling.size() - 1; ++i)
        cv::line(canvasMask, strokeSampling[i], strokeSampling[i + 1], cv::Scalar::all(255));

    // computing a distance map:
    cv::Mat tmp1 = 255 - canvasMask;
    cv::Mat distMap;
    cv::distanceTransform(tmp1, distMap, CV_DIST_L2, CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE);

    float outerRadius = 50;
    float innerRadius = 10;
    cv::Scalar strokeColor = cv::Scalar::all(0);

    for (int y = 0; y < distMap.rows; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < distMap.cols; ++x)
        {
            float percentage = 0.0f;
            float radius = distMap.at<float>(y, x);

            if (radius>outerRadius){ percentage = 0.0; }      // transparent
            else
            if (radius<innerRadius){ percentage = 1.0; }      // solid
            else
            {
                percentage = 1 - ((radius - innerRadius) / (outerRadius - innerRadius));  // partial
            }

            if (percentage > 0)
            {
                // here you could use the canvasMask if you like to, instead of directly drawing on the canvas
                cv::Vec3b canvasColor = canvas.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x);
                cv::Vec3b cColor = cv::Vec3b(strokeColor[0], strokeColor[1], strokeColor[2]);
                canvas.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x) = percentage*cColor + (1 - percentage) * canvasColor;
            }
        }

    cv::imshow("out", canvas);
    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Output/stroke.png", canvas);
    cv::waitKey(0);

}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how I could eliminate the "folds" on the inner corners?

Comment: I think those should be artifacts from the distance transform, which is optimized for speed, not for precision. But didn't test it.

Comment: I looked to implement this, but unfortunately this only works if we have the complete line ahead of time.

Comment: you will need some kind of "temporary layer" or at least the current line in work as some kind of working set.